# $\xi$ is the least upper bound of $M$.

Tags: real-analysis

> $M$ is a set with upper bound.

Should set $M$ be an ordered set? or by deafult it is an ordered set, since it maybe an sub set of $R$.  When we say a subset $M$ of $R$(ordered set), is $M$ also an ordered set?

> a cut $S=(\xi )$ is denoted as the set made up of the left part of $\xi$
>
> (1) $\eta \in S$$\Leftrightarrow$  there exsists  $\zeta \in M$,  such that  $\eta \text{$<$=}\zeta$, we can define a cut in  $R$  that $S=(\xi )$,  and  $\xi$  is the least upper bound of  $M$.

I know $\eta \text{$<$=}\zeta$ means $\eta$ is not the largest number of of $S$, what's the relation with $\xi$ and $\zeta$? no typo? can you explain me about (1)

Comment: You need to give more context to get an answer. From some of the wording, it look like it's taken from a construction of the real numbers via Dedekind's cuts. (And in that case I would expect $M$ to be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: @rmf I donot know, there is no word about $M$ is subset of $R$ or $Q$, from Garding's Encounter with mathematics. Chapter 5.

Comment: "Least upper bound" for set $M$ is $\inf M$. Consider editing your post and explaining yourself more carefully, I find it very hard to understand your question.

Comment: Sorry. "Least upper bound" for set $M$ is $\sup M$, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify some points.

If $M$ has an upper bound, the elements of $M$ and the elements of its wider context need to be ordered.

An upper bound for $M$ need not be a member of $M$ - take $M$ to be the set $0\le x \le 1$; $2$ is greater than every element of this set, and is therefore an upper bound for it.

The least upper bound for $M$ need not be a member of $M$ - take $M$ to be the set $0\le x \lt 1$ which has least upper bound $1 \notin M$.

Note that I have chosen examples which work for rational numbers or real numbers.

In the definition you cite $\zeta$ is defined to be a member of $M$. By contrast $\xi$ need not be a member of $M$ - to take account of the situation where the least upper bound is not an element of $M$ - as in my second example.

The definition wants to collect together every number in our context (eg real or rational) for which we can definitely say $x \le \xi$ (the equality case might not occur, depending on context). However we don't initially know what the value of $\xi$ is or whether it is a member of $M$. So we gather together as set $S$ every number which is less than or equal some element of $M$ - such numbers are necessarily $\le \xi$.

In fact the definition is using that set of numbers $S$ to define the unknown number $\xi$.

Comment: $\zeta  \text{$>$=} \xi$ right?

Comment: @spuorg-imes No. $\zeta \le \xi$ because $\zeta \in M$ and if $\xi$ is to be an upper bound for $M$, $\xi$ must be greater than or equal to any element of $M$.

Comment: $S$ is the closure of $M$? or $M\subset S$?

Comment: @spuorg-imes Suppose $M$ consists of the points $0\le m \lt 1$ then $S$ would be all the points $s \lt 1$. We know that we will always have $M\subset S$, because if $m \in M$ we can choose $\zeta=m$ and, for this choice of $\zeta$ we have $m \le \zeta$ so that $m \in S$.